# Using functions as input for a function - won't simplify

Tags: functions

I've defined a function

P[k_] :=  1/[Sqrt]2 (R[k] + L[k])

where R and L generate matrices. However the output of this function never full simplifies (even when I use the Simplify[%] functions). It always leaves the output at 1 over root 2 followed by each of the matrices with the binary operator.

Can anyone tell me what I need to do to simplify this output?

Comment: Please post complete minimal code, including definitions for all functions involved. Perhaps explain what you're trying to accomplish. At the very least, the syntax of the `Sqrt` part looks wonky.

Comment: L[k_] := Table[KroneckerDelta[i + 1, j] Sqrt[i], {i, k}, {j, k}] // MatrixForm

Comment: R[k_] := Table[KroneckerDelta[i, j + 1] Sqrt[j], {i, k}, {j, k}] // MatrixForm

Comment: P[k_] := 1/\[Sqrt]2 ((R[k] + L[k])

Comment: Enclosing the `Sqrt` in brackets doesn't make much sense

Comment: The Sqrt function is correct, for some reason it just changes when I post it here :/

Comment: So is it Sqrt[2]? In any case drop the `//MatrixForm` - that is a display form.

Comment: Bleh, that was the problem - thanks for your help!